# How to create a shared channel via Slack conversation API?

Tags: slack-api

I would like to programmatically create a channel in Slack, make it shared and get the invitatino link. I found two APIS: [conversations.create](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.create) and [conversations.invite](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.invite) but they'r only applicable to channels within the workspace. Doesn't seem what I want to do is possible with the Slack APIs currently, but wanted to see if anybody had a work around.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [conversations.inviteShared](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.inviteShared) API method.

> This [Slack Connect API](https://api.slack.com/apis/connect) method creates an invitation to a [Slack
> Connect](https://api.slack.com/apis/channels-between-orgs) channel. The invitation can be sent to users or bots in
> another workspace either as a shareable URL or as an email invite.
>
> The invited user must be known to your app (i.e., a channel is already
> shared between the organization your app is installed on and the
> organization of the user).
>
> If the channel to be joined is not already a Slack Connect channel, it
> becomes a Connect channel when you use this method to invite users
> from another workspace.

Here's what worked for me:

### Step 1: Create a Slack Channel via Vanilla JS

```js
  // Headers
  const headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + yourAPIToken
  }

  // Create Slack channel
  let create = await fetch('https://slack.com/api/conversations.create', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      'team_id': 'CXXXXXXX' // Your team id,
      'is_private': true, // Optional. Create a private channel instead of a public one 
      'name': 'your-channel' // Your desired channel name
    })
  }).then(response => response.json());

console.log(create);
```

### Step 2: Invite yourself (and/or default users)

**This is important. Otherwise no one will see the channel.**

```js
// Invite default users
let invite = await fetch('https://slack.com/api/conversations.invite', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify({
        channel: create.channel.id,
        users: 'XXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXX' // A comma separated list of user IDs.
      })
  }).then(response => response.json());

console.log(invite);
```

### Step 3: Invite external users via email

```js
// Invite default users
// NOTE: The body object wasn't accepted for some reason, so moved it to the URI instead.
let inviteShared = await fetch('https://slack.com/api/conversations.inviteShared?channel=' 
                      + create.channel.id + '&emails=' 
                      + encodeURIComponent('yourExternal@email.com'), {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: headers,
          }).then(response => response.json());

console.log(inviteShared);
```